# What is __AS3__?

Tags: actionscript-3

Sometimes in debug mode with Flash Builder, I see something like

```
__AS3__.vec.Vector.<Object> (@909e219)
```

but when I try to store this variable in another as3 variable, Flash duplicate this variable. Concretly, I'm trying to exclude some values on `dragInitiator.selectedItems` property before adding them to a `List` but when I use `splice` method on it, values aren't deleted from this vector.

So how can I acces variable with `__AS3__` namespace please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a Tamarin developer:

> The namespace "__AS3__.vec" is an artifact of a time when we did not have good API
>   versioning and could not introduce new top-level names without the risk of breaking
>   existing code.  Today we would probably have made "Vector" public & versioned.

Source: http://hg.mozilla.org/tamarin-redux/rev/817f3e019ba2#l2.30

In other words, `__AS3__` is the package where are defined Flash internal classes into Tamarin VM.

To access such variables, you don't need to specify the namespace. You only have to use the FQN declared in `playerglobals.swc`.